# Issue in AsyncItemWriter with Spring Batch 5

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have upgraded my spring boot version from 2.7.9 to 3.0.5 and facing some issues in implementing `AsyncItemWriter`.

Following is my code snippet:

```
@Bean
    public AsyncItemWriter<myDto> asyncWriter() {
        AsyncItemWriter<myDto> asyncItemWriter = new AsyncItemWriter<>();
        asyncItemWriter.setDelegate(eventMessageItemWriter());
        return asyncItemWriter;
    }
```

And the `eventMessageItemWriter` is defined as:

```
public class EventMessageItemWriter implements ItemWriter<myDto> {

    @Autowired
    private Myservice myservice;

    @Override
    public void write(Chunk<? extends myDto> chunk) throws Exception {
        for (myDto rqData : chunk) {
            myservice.insertRequestData(rqData);
        }
        
    }
```

And I am getting following error:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.batch.integration.async.AsyncItemWriter does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void write(org.springframework.batch.item.Chunk)' of interface org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter.

Can anyone please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely have a version mismatch. Spring Boot 3 uses Spring Batch 5. In Spring Batch 5, the ItemWriter interface was changed from `write(List<? extends T> items)` to `write(Chunk<? extends T> chunk)`.

AsyncItemWriter however is in [Spring Batch Integration](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-integration). My guess is that you're using Spring Batch Integration 4, which still implements the old ItemWriter interface, causing a runtime exception. Upgrading to Spring Batch Integration 5 should fix this.

Comment: Any hint about performance?
in my project, with this update the performance became morw slow than 1000%
to write 2M of record from 6 minutes now need more than 1h